# Logstash not reading json file

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I've config like this

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/opt/data/user-*.json"
        type => "json"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        tags => ["user"]
    }
}

filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }

}
```

When I run logstash with `--debug`, it shows the message without any output, seems it keep waiting for new content to be consumed (but I've set `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"` already)

```
_globbed_files: /opt/data/user-*.json: glob is: ["/opt/data/user-2016-08-08.json"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"346", :method=>"_globbed_files"}
Pushing flush onto pipeline {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"458", :method=>"flush"}
Pushing flush onto pipeline {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"458", :method=>"flush"}
```

When I change the input to stdin and paste the json in my data file, then it is ok.

```
input {
    stdin{}
}
```

Comment: How old is your file? file input will ignore files older that 24 hours.

Comment: does logstash have access to your file system?